# Output of a function in R change with the number of inputs

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, time

I am trying to run a function to download data from the USGS website using `dataRetrieval` package of R and a function I have created called `getstreamflow`. The code is the following:

```
siteNumber <- c("094985005","09498501","09489500","09489499","09498502") 
Streamflow <- sapply(siteNumber, function(siteNumber) tryCatch(getstreamflow(siteNumber), error = function(e) message(paste("Error in station ", siteNumber))))
Streamflow <- Filter(NROW,Streamflow) #to delete empty data frames
```

I got the output I want that it is the one shown in the image below:
[image]

However, when I ran the same code but increase the number of stations in the input `siteNumber`

The output change and instead to produce several dataframes inside of a list. It generates a list for each data frame.
[image]

Does someone know why this happens? It is the same function only changes the number of stations in the `siteNumber`

Comment: Question would be better targeted to package authors. You may have caught a bug or missed a note in docs. Ask question/raise issue on their dev page: https://github.com/usgs/dataRetrieval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the image showed in the new data, each element in the `list` is nested as a list.  We can extract the `list` element (of length 1) with `[[1]]` and then apply the `Filter`

```
out <- Filter(NROW, lapply(Streamflow, function(x) x[[1]]))
```

---

As we used `NROW`, it passed the test for `list` as well where it returns 1 for `length` attribute of `list` and thus all the elements meet the condition TRUE.  Also, in the previous step, OP uses `sapply` and `sapply` is one function which can sometimes simplify the output.  Instead of `sapply` use `lapply` (or specify `simplify = FALSE`)